# How to make google search results default to python3 docs

Tags: python-3.x, google-search

I like to use google when I'm searching for documentation on things related to python. Many times what I am looking for turns out to be in the official python documentation on docs.python.org. Unfortunately, at time of writing, the docs for the python 2.x branch tend to rank much higher on google than the 3.x branch, and I often end up having to switch to the 3.x branch after loading the page for the 2.x documentation. The designers of docs.python.org have made it easy to switch between python versions, which is great; but I just find it annoying to have to switch python versions and wait an extra page load every time I follow a link from google.

Has anyone has done anything to combat this? I'd love to hear your solutions.

Here's what I've tried so far:

- clicking on the python 3.x link farther down - this works sometimes, but often the discrepancy in ranking between 2.x and 3.x results is quite big, and the 3.x things are hard to find.
- copying the url from the search result and manually replacing the 2 with 3 - this works but is also inconvenient.

Comment: If you are a mod and you think this question belongs to the lifehacking stack exchange, feel free to move it over. I posted here because it might find its way to more python3 users.

Answer (score 4):

Often when searching for Python stuff, I add the search term "python" anyway because many names refer to entirely different things in the world as well. Using "python3" here appears to solve your problem. I also feel it a lot less unobtrusive than the hacks you describe.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest adding a custom search for python3 docs, if your browser allows it (works in firefox), which would automatically append site= and domain= to google search query, and show only py3 links.

Specific search query I use:

```
https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=Mozilla-search&domains=docs.python.org&sitesearch=docs.python.org/3&q={searchTerms}
```

(firefox replaces `{searchTerms}` with whatever's typed as a search query)